# Return to top after click on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, return, anchor

I have a simple question for You.
It is possible to return to top after click on image, which is reference to jquery content?
For example: When I choose an image in "Portfolio" on http://dash.com.pl/ I need to return to top of this (#portfolio). Thank You for Your help.

Comment: Yes that is possible. Good luck.

Comment: Thank You so much:D May I ask You how to do this?

Comment: Yes, you may ask that.

Comment: By using `jQuery.scrollTop(x)` where the `x` is the value the page should scroll to. You have to find the x by checking the position of your `#Portfolio`

Comment: Some people on here think they're something special.  If he's doing something wrong then explain what it is, rather than get your e-peen out and start making a fool of yourself.

Comment: Archer - You're wrong. putvande - thank You, I hope it will help me:)

Comment: Lukas - I was actually asking them to stop mocking you and be more helpful.  No worries.  I'll leave it then.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand You well:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use a link attribute

```
<div id="portfolio">...</div>  
<a href="#portfolio">
  <img src="screen.png">
</a>
```

With jquery you can get element's position and scorll to the top

```
scroll(0, $('#portfolio').position().top)
```

Update: 
Correct the  jquery scroll example it need the x value.

Comment: I'll try your method.

Comment: My images are referenced to other index file. In this file I put Your jquery code, and after click on image, possition is scrolling to top, but not to #portfolio.

Comment: Your code works fine, but I have one more problem. It is possible to add extra space from top? When you click, navigate covers header and I need to scroll a little higher.

Comment: this returns the position of the element in the window $('#portfolio').position().top to just add or substract from it to move further up or down

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need javascript for that, anchors will scroll to an ID if you supply a hash as the href ?

```
<a href="#portfolio"><img src="image/to/click.png" /></a>
```

doing just `<a href="#"></a>` scrolls to the top, and for other pages it's the same
`<a href="http://mysite.com/some/other/page/#divToScrollTo"></a>`

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help:/

Answer (score 0):

Done. Thank You everybody for Your help.
This code helped me:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(this).scrollTop(3200);
});
```